# URL rewrite skipping folder name using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a website for listing education centers.I have two doubts.

1. I have a URL for printing one college details like this

   **www.example.com/education/eduS.php?Main=colleges&Name=nameOfCollege**

I rwrite this url like this

```
www.example.com/education/colleges/nameOfCollege
```

my htaccess is

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ eduS.php?Main=$1&Name=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

My problem is that

- I want to skip the folder name eduaction from my url so as to get URL like this

  **www.example.com/colleges/nameOfCollege**
  How it is possible. I want to get Main and Name as GET parameters.
- my Second problem is that , I have another url for listing colleges name in one page. The url like this

  **www.example.com/education/edu.php?Main=colleges&Category=Engineering-colleges**
  I rewrite like this

  **www.example.com/education/colleges/Engineering-colleges**
  my htaccess

  **RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2 [L,NC,QSA]**
  but this shows little bit confusion. The above two URL have same number of GET parameters. How can I handle this problem.
- I also need to skip same folder name education from the second URL. Anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ education/eduS.php?Main=$1&Name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This allows you to have your URLs like: `/colleges/nameOfCollege`

Comment: thank you sir.sir how can i handle two URL with same number and same type of parameters in my above second question.

Comment: Other rule you have is in `/education/.htaccess` which is for `/education/colleges/nameOfCollege` URL and this one s for `/colleges/nameOfCollege`

Comment: sir above htaccess not working in my locallhost. Object not found error shows

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess? Did you try: `www.keralaspot.com/colleges/nameOfCollege` ?

Comment: sir **/colleges/nameOfCollege** and **/colleges/Category** two URL have same number and type of parameters. URL redirect nor properly

Comment: yes sir. I stoped search engine crowling before 3 week. I want URL rewrite. That is my new website 3 month age.

Comment: Yes you cannot have 2 pretty URLs with exact 2 parameters. But at least one should work if placed in DOCUMENT_ROOT

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46807/discussion-between-nidhin-punnakkara-and-anubhava)

Comment: Hi could you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895224/make-htaccess-rule-apply-only-to-the-current-folder