# Make htaccess rule apply only to the current folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I saw this example of how to change index.php to the url name

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_.]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_.]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&goto=$2 [NC,L]
```

This `.htaccess` file is inside the `www.site.com/map/` directory

so what it does is change from `www.site.com/map/index.php` to `www.site.com/map/country`

it rewrite index.php to the country name in url, the problem is when I acess a directory above or sub directory like `www.site.com/map/countryname/state` it just `replace the`index.php`inside the state directory to the`index.php`inside the map directory` how to solve this ? or how to make this applied to the current directory only ?

Here is the site dir structure  http://ufile.io/3dii7  so when I go to `site/map/state/` it works but i need the country name in url to acess state dir like this `site/map/country/state/`

Comment: What is your expected output for `www.site.com/map/countryname/state`? I mean what you want to execute for this `URL` and also mention what error message you are getting `500`,`404` or `403`

Comment: No error messages but `www.site.com/map/countryname/state` it just get the same index.php inside `www.site.com/map/countryname` but I need the other index.php inside the dir `www.site.com/map/countryname/state`

Comment: maybe `DirectoryIndex` has a root-relative value `/index.php`

Comment: the .htaccess file is inside the `/map/` directory

Comment: so the second rule matches `countryname/state` with `/map/.htaccess`

Comment: yes is just replace the index.php file of `countryname/state` to the index.php file inside `map`dir , how to solve this ?

Comment: all the `RewriteCond` set should be repeated also for the 2nd rule, in order to not affect filesystem paths.

Comment: `RewriteCond` is only in effect for next `RewriteRule`. Due to this your 3 conditions are only being used for first `RewriteRule`. You can avoid repetition of conditions by using them in a separate exclusion rule.

Comment: @anubhava explain me more what I should I do, how my .htaccess would be like to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your .htaccess as this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all rules below this for files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-.]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/map/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(.+)/?$ $2?id=$1&goto=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/map/$2/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-.]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ $2/index.php?id=$1&goto=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-.]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&goto=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: It's still replacing the `index.php` file in the dir `www.site.com/map/country/state` to the index.php file in the `www.site.com/map/` how to make it applied to the current /map/ dir this is where the .htacess file is

Comment: `map` is directory, so  countryname is the file **index.php** inside the map directory which the current .htaccess rule will rewrite the index.php to the country name. Inside the `map` there is the dir `/state/`

Comment: Here is the following site dir structure https://ufile.io/3dii7 so when I go to `site/map/state/` it works but i need the country name in url to acess state dir like this `site/map/country/state/`

Comment: when I enter `http://example.com/map/abcd/state` it loads the index.php inside `map` dir . I need it to load the index.php inside `state` dir

Comment: still same problem

Comment: `localhost/site/` than all files inside it `map`etc `state` is inside map dir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143913/discussion-between-anubhava-and-developer).

Comment: Another doubt, how to make the `state` folder also reconize **files.php** just like the `map` folder does?

Comment: inside the state `folder` there are also `search.php` file

Comment: this is the url `site/map/country/state/search.php`

Comment: And how should `site/map/country/state/search.php` be rewritten to?

Comment: I can not acess the file `/state/search.php` , only `/state/index.php`

Comment: Use the correct URL i.e. `/site/map/state/search.php`

Comment: it works but when I go to add the country name in url not works  `www.site.com/map/countryname/state/search.php`

Comment: I have updated answer based on your comments but please don't add new requirements via comments section. You can create a new question for these cases.